# tmux becomes unresponsive when tailing a quickly updated file

Tags: command-line, tmux, logs

I have a log file that I am writing a few hundred lines to a second. I want to tail this in a tmux pane.

However, when I do this tmux becomes unresponsive - I can't change panes or windows and I can't even CTRL+C to stop tail.

After about 3 or so minutes tail will eventually be killed by CTRL+C and I will regain control - but until then I can't do anything (except change from terminal to another window such as my browser).

Is there anyway to resolve this? I suspect that the issue is being caused because so many lines are being written to the log file.

Comment: Have you tried tail without tmux? Have you tried it on another machine?

Comment: Your question sounds more of a bug report to me. And bugs are off-topic here. http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 4):

The problem is more likely to be tmux overhead, especially if you've got a vertical split on your pane. You can set tmux to not update the screen when there are a bunch of control characters being written. See `man tmux` for more details, but I have the following in my **~/.tmux.conf**.

```
set -g c0-change-trigger 20 #default is 250
set -g c0-change-interval 1000 #default is 100
```

This tells tmux that when 20 control sequences per milliseconds are being printed to the screen, tmux should change it's update interval to once per 1000 milliseconds (1/sec).

Comment: looks good, but I had to use `c0-change-trigger` instead of `c0-trigger`

Comment: thanks @YoavAner. I edited my answer. It c0-change-trigger was what I meant.

Comment: For reference this made no improvements

Comment: Note that starting with tmux version 2.1, `The c0-* options for rate-limiting have been removed.  Instead, a backoff approach is used` (see the [changelog](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/CHANGES)). As of right now the version that you get from the main ubuntu repositories is 2.3, so if you recently installed it you won't have support for those options.

Answer (score 2):

This has been greatly improved in tmux 2.1.

The c0- options metioned in other answers have been removed and a back off approach to buffering introduced: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tmux/tmux/master/CHANGES

Answer (score 1):

This is NOT likely to be caused by tailing log file which is being written a few hundred times per second.

Try to ssh to the box or open another terminal session, use `strace` to attach to the `tmux` process, see the system calls made by and signals received by the process. This will definitely help.

Example:
`strace -tT -pPID`

Output to a file
`strace -tT -pPID -o /path/to/tmux_output`

> NOTE: `strace` is a light-weight debugger, it helped me to solve several tmux related problem in the past, e.g. tmux not able to create / remove files/directories in `/var/run` or `/run`.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this will not solve your problem, but try to pipe the output of the command to either `less` or `more`:

- `less` allows you to scroll from within even a non-scrollable terminal:

  ```
  <command> | less
  ```
- `more` prints a page then you press enter to bring up every line after that:

  ```
  <command> | more
  ```